# Generating jsf checkboxs

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow-2

I have a multiselect listbox and depending on how many elements user will choose I have to show same number of checkboxes. I'm using jsf and primefaces /spring webflow. How I can do that? Any examples?
And I have to make one checkbox which allow to check all generated checkboxes using one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have a multiselect listbox*

Thus, a `<h:selectManyListbox>` with a fixed `<f:selectItems>` value.

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="listbox" value="#{bean.selectedListboxItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableListboxItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

With something like:

```
private List<String> availableListboxItems;
private List<String> selectedListboxItems;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableListboxItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    availableListboxItems.add("menu item 1");
    availableListboxItems.add("menu item 2");
    availableListboxItems.add("menu item 3");
}
```

---

> *and depending on how many elements user will choose I have to show same number of checkboxes*

Thus, just prepopulate the `<f:selectItems>` of a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` based on the value of the `<h:selectManyListbox>`.

```
<h:commandButton value="Generate checkboxes">
    <f:ajax execute="listbox" listener="#{bean.generateCheckboxes}" render="checkboxes" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="checkboxes" value="#{bean.selectedCheckboxItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableCheckboxItems}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

with something like

```
private List<String> availableCheckboxItems;
private List<String> selectedCheckboxItems;

public void generateCheckboxes() {
    availableCheckboxItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= selectedListboxItems.size(); i++) {
        availableCheckboxItems.add("checkbox item " + i);
    }
}
```

---

> *I'm using jsf and primefaces /spring webflow. How I can do that? Any examples?*

I believe the above trivial examples are sufficient. For PrimeFaces, just replace `<h:xxx>` with `<p:xxx>`. I have however no idea how Spring Webflow plays a role in this as I have never used it.

---

> *And I have to make one checkbox which allow to check all generated checkboxes using one click.*

That's left as an exercise for you. Hint: make sure that `availableCheckboxItems` contains the desired values depending on the current value of the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` which should represent the "toggle selected items".

Comment: Great answer :) But how I can made some of checkboxes checked while creating? And second, You put there all strings, but how should I do when I use objects of my class eg car and I want to store objects in list after select in Listbox. I mean my object should have toString method or how jsf manage this?

Comment: 1) Just prefill `selectedCheckboxItems`. 2) It's just a basic example.   In your case, just implement a `Converter`.

Comment: Talking about last thing in my question, should I just after check proper checkbox set all elements in selectedCheckboxItems and rerender <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> ?